# Trying to use Script to auto increment build in Xcode 7.3.1, Permission Denied Error

Tags: shell, build, xcode7

I was able to find some code to automate incrementing my build number in Xcode, but I don't seem to be getting quiet right. I'm hoping someone can fill in the missing pieces for me or show me where I went wrong.

I found the code here: http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/automatic-xcode-versioning-with-git/

So this is what I have for my .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

git=$(sh /etc/profile; which git)
number_of_commits=$("$git" rev-list HEAD --count)
git_release_version=$("$git" describe --tags --always --abbrev=0)

target_plist="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
dsym_plist="$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME/Contents/Info.plist"

for plist in "$target_plist" "$dsym_plist"; do
    if [ -f "$plist" ]; then
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $number_of_commits" "$plist"
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString ${git_release_version#*v}" "$plist"
fi
done
```

And this is what I have in my Build Phases in Xcode:
[image]

And finally, this is the error I'm seeing:
[image]

/Users/bradyj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EZ_List-cszvlpxrrxpivsbycnlcjdlambst/Build/Intermediates/EZ List.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EZ List.build/Script-31BC8DAE1D37F5CC00C837E2.sh: line 2: /Users/bradyj/Documents/_Jason General/Xcode/EZ List/Scripts/set_build_number.sh: Permission denied